# Can gate level verilog and behavioral Verilog be mixed?

Tags: verilog

I have been working on a very simple example of verilog. Could a blocking expression be used in a gate module?

I don't know if the sentence `out=0;` is right or wrong there in that module. Would this module be simulated?

```
module what_is_it (in1, in2, in3, out);
 output out;
 input in1, in2, in3;
out = 0;
 and a1(a1_o, in1, in3);
 and a2(a2_o, in2, ~in3);
 or o1(out, a1_o, a2_o);
endmodule
```

Comment: correct verilog (gate or not) would be `assign out = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not valid. Even if you would add the `assign` keyword to get rid of possible compilation errors, `out` would be undefined.

Lets ignore `out = 0` for a second. You could rewrite your module as

```
module what_is_it (in1, in2, in3, out);
   output out;
   input in1, in2, in3;

   assign out = (in1 && in3) || (in2 && ~in3);
endmodule
```

With this representation, it is clearer that `out` would be ***continuously*** assigned ([Section 10.3, IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe526/2012%20System%20Verilog%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf)) with a logical combination of the input ports.

Adding `(assign) out = 0` before that would not make sense, since you would continuously drive the same signal from two different sources.

If you want a blocking assignment, you should wrap your logic in a combinational always block. See the example below.

```
module what_is_it (in1, in2, in3, out);
   output reg out;
   input in1, in2, in3;

   always @(*) begin
       out = 0;
       out = (in1 && in3) || (in2 && ~in3);
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. As far as I have understood, I must use assign when the process of transfering data is not continuous, i.e. the code is not in an always loop. If there is an always loop with some condition, I should use reg. Am I right or wrong? Thanks for your help

Comment: No. You should use `assign` when the process of transfering data _is_ continuous. You should, furthermore, not think of `always @(*)` as a traditional loop. Translated, this means as much as: "Always execute if anything at the right-handside of an assignment changes". `reg` and `wire` can be a bit confusion in Verilog. If you are going to assign your variable inside an always block, you should use a `reg`, yes.